# How to scale canvas in javascript after filled by text?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm printing canvas which is in iFrame. When I print it resolution show too bad.

I think I should make the canvas more larger and scale it to normal size..

HTML :

```
<iframe width="80px" height="80px" id="printframe">
```

JS :

```
var frame = document.getElementById("printframe");
var frame_canvas = frame.contentWindow.document;
frame_canvas.body.innerHTML = '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="980px" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>';

var canvas = frame_canvas.getElementById("myCanvas");

canvas.getContext("2d").scale(0.5, 0.5); // should it be make the 
canvas smaller? its not working

var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
context.font = "50px"; // normal size is 10px
context.fillText("This is text to print !!!");

frame.contentWindow.print(); // it prints but resolution is too bad
```

Is there any way to scale it, or make canvas resolution more better ?

Help me and Thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

A canvas actually has two sizes: the size of the element itself and the size of the element’s drawing surface. Setting the element's width and height attributes sets both of these sizes; CSS attributes affect only the element’s size and not the drawing surface.

One work around is to set the Canvas' Height and Weight through JavaScript like below:

```
var canvas = frame_canvas.getElementById("myCanvas");

canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
```

If this does not work you can try scaling the canvas like shown below:

```
context.scale(2,2);
```